# scala error ambiguous reference to overloaded definition

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and trying to learn scala.
I am trying to write below 2 classes but getting the below error.
Please help me

```
scala> class Point(val x: Int,val y: Int)
defined class Point

scala> class Rectangle(val topleft: Point,val bottomright: Point){
     | def topleft: Point
     | def bottomright: Point
     | def left=topleft.x
     | def right=bottomright.x
     | def width=right-left
     | }


<console>:14: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both value topleft in class Rectangle of type => Point
and  method topleft in class Rectangle of type => Point
match expected type ?
       def left=topleft.x
                ^


<console>:15: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both value bottomright in class Rectangle of type => Point
and  method bottomright in class Rectangle of type => Point
match expected type ?
       def right=bottomright.x
                 ^
<console>:13: error: value bottomright is defined twice
  conflicting symbols both originated in file '<console>'
       def bottomright: Point
           ^

<console>:12: error: value topleft is defined twice
  conflicting symbols both originated in file '<console>'
       def topleft: Point
```

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please define the Rectangle class as below without topleft and bottomright:-

```
scala> class Rectangle(val topleft: Point,val bottomright: Point){
     | def left=topleft.x
     | def right=bottomright.x
     | def width=right-left
     | }
defined class Rectangle
```

Answer (score 3):

You have defined `topleft` and `bottomright` twice. Simply remove the following two lines to fix the error:

```
def topleft: Point
def bottomright: Point
```

Comment: Thanks marstran, Just want to know 1 detail in the class I have used val topleft: Point,val bottomright: Point as vals and def topleft: Point
     | def bottomright: Point as methods, in scala can't we use the same name for val and def which are methods

Comment: No, you can not. How would you know which is which when you refer to it? A `def` is just an expression that will be evaluated every time you use it. A `val` is an expression that is evaluated only once, and that happens immediately.